# Jaws issue with knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, jaws-screen-reader

I am using Jaws screen reader for accessibility web development.I am facing an issue while binding the values using knock out.The order in which the jaws announces the web content is different.
The content is

**Name Changes**

**Date Received : 2015-03-08**

**View Date : 2015-12-29**

It reads in the following order  Date Received : View Date : 2015-12-29 Name Changes 2015-03-08.

The dates are the binded values.
My code is

```
        <p>
            <span class="bold" @ko.Bind.Text(m => m.Type)></span>
            <br />
            @LocalizationManager.GetString("CBA_FAT_Recieved_Date_Label_Copy") : <span @ko.Bind.Text(m => m.Date)></span>
            <br />
            @{
            if(Model.ViewedDate != "") {<span>@LocalizationManager.GetString("CBA_FAT_View_Date_Label_Copy") : <span>@Model.ViewedDate</span></span>}
            }
        </p>
```

The issue is with the knockout binded values in the span tag.
Is there any way i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very complicated question. Because every tag will not work with Jaws. Please use another tool. In the market a lot of tools are available for this purpose. It is better to avoid the tool JAWS.

Also while working with knockout, its better to avoid server side scripting instead use client side knockout scripts. In internet explorer, JAWS having somme loading issues.

Please see the below link.

[Sortsite](http://www.powermapper.com/download/sortsite/sortsite-user-manual.pdf)